# Change dtype of a Pd DataFrame using a for loop

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a DataFrame that has 400 columns, and I need to change the dtype from object to categorical for all of the 400 columns, how can I use loops to do that?

Comment: Not a `machine-learning` question, kindly do not spam irrelevant tags (removed).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
df = df.astype(pd.CategoricalDtype())
```

Comment: @GairikChakraborty please do not use the comments space for asking (irrelevant) follow-up questions; open a new question instead.